# Update one element of javascript array updates all elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I initialized array with default object and I want to update property in one element. Unfortunately there are updated all elements of list. My code is following:

```js
let object = {person: {
  name: '',
  age: 0
}};

let list = [...Array(2)].map(x => ({...object}));

list[0].person.name = 'John';

var myJSON = JSON.stringify(list);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myJSON;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
```

What is problem with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course

```js
let object = {person: {
  name: '',
  age: 0
}};

let list = [...Array(2)].map(x => ({...object}));
console.log( 'object are differents', list[0] !== list[1] );
console.log( 'person are differents', list[0].person !== list[1].person );
```

Just change with

```js
let object = {person: {
  name: '',
  age: 0
}};

let list = [...Array(2)].map(x => ({ person: {name:'', age:0}}) );
console.log( 'object are differents', list[0] !== list[1] );
console.log( 'person are differents', list[0].person !== list[1].person );
```

Your error is that destructuring is not a deep copy. So you use always the same `person` object.

```
{...object}
is same as
{ person: object.person }
```

**Edition**

As you want a deep copy of `object`, this is how you can do it very simply:

```js
let object = {person: {
  name: '',
  age: 0
}};

let list = [...Array(2)].map(x => {
   return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object));
});

console.log( 'object are differents', list[0] !== list[1] );
console.log( 'person are differents', list[0].person !== list[1].person );
```

Comment: Is method to create new object depend on created object? It is only sample, but I have really complex object with initialization in many places with inheriting. I thought using {...object} instead of object will create for me new object.

Comment: So create it with `const new = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(object));`to have a deep copy, I will edit the answer

Comment: Now whatever your `object` is, you will have a totally deep copy of it

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your creating a copy of your object twice `.map(x => ({...object}))` but inside your object you have another object, that one is not copied. so the copy has a property "person" that is pointing to the same place in memory, you need to either do a deep copy or just add new empty objects.